# missing arrays in .data section MIPS

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am working on a program in MIPS using MARS simulator to read and write .pgm files. It consists of several files containing different helper functions, but for the purposes of this question, there are 2 files of concern: main.asm, and writeimage.asm.

In the .data segment of writeimage.asm, I want to initialize:
    a string literal "P5\n"
    a string literal "P2\n"
    a buffer size, so that I can play with this parameter without having to hardcode a buffer size.

Here is the 'preamble' (if I may call it that) of writeimage.asm:

```
                  .data
myStack:          .space 5
writeBuffer:      .space 128
                  .align 2
writeBufferSize:  .word 128
                  .align 2
p5:               .ascii "P5\n"
                  .align 2
p2:               .ascii "P2\n"
                  .text
                  .globl write_image
                  write_image: ...
```

For some reason, when run my program from main, when I try to access `writeBufferSize` like so:

```
la $t0, writeBufferSize
lw $s0, ($t0)
```

the value loaded into `$s0` is zero. Also, the strings `p2` and `p5` do not seem to exist at the addresses MARS says they are in. Later on in the code I try to write these stings to a file, and when I load the address of the string into `$a1` and perform the syscall, what gets printed to the file is nothing; and when I look at the address that is loaded into `$a1`, and use the debugger to see the contents of that memory address, it's blank, as if the string never existed.

I do not have this issue when I assemble writeimage.asm only, only when I assemble from main, and when I assemble all files in the directory.

I am very frustrated by this, and I really don't want to go hard coding buffer lengths throughout my code. Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my experience:

## Scenario A

main.asm:

```
    .data
    .extern p3, 4   # this will be commented out in some of the other scenarios
    .text
    la $t0, p3
    lw $t1, ($t0)
```

a.asm:

```
    .data
    .globl p3       # this will be commented out in some of the other scenarios
p3: .word 200
```

Build:

1. Check "Assemble all files in directory"
2. Open a.asm, and activate the window
3. Assemble

Result: It works fine, gets the right data value into `$t1`: `200`.

## Scenario B

Same as Scenario A except that for build step (2.) activate the window for main.asm instead

Result: It gets an assembler error (hence won't run)!

Apparently, if it sees the `.globl` first, the `.extern` in another file is fine, but if it see `.extern` first, the `.globl` is considered contradictory.

## Scenario C

main.asm: same as Scenario A, except comment out the `.extern` in `main.asm`

a.asm: unchanged from Scenario A

Result: both build scenarios like A & B work properly!

## Scenario D

main.asm: unchanged from Scenario A (i.e. using `.extern`)

a.asm: missing (comment out) the `.globl` directive

Result: No matter which window is activated upon assemble, no assembly errors, but incorrect code.  The label references location `0x10000000`, not the proper `0x10010000`.  Thus, zero is loaded into `$t1`.

Apparently the `.extern` satisfies the assembler, so it silently allows this, even though there is no true definition of the label.

---

Recommendation: Scenario C — use `.globl`, but do not use `.extern`!

Also, the file whose window is activated (foremost) when the assemble button is pushed seems to be the one that goes "first" for `.text` and `.data`, so that one will have the simulator entry point, for example — as a result, you want to assemble with your main in the foremost window.

Comment: thank you for this detailed response, I will assume it'll be useful to someone, but I found the error and basically it boiled down to a design decision that made it so that I was accessing memory I shouldn't have, and I overwrote the strings I set in the .data section. Thanks again!